# Is there any issue with the way i'm detecting mobile devices

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mobile, cross-browser

I've checked various related questions already posted about detecting mobile devices for websites, but my method is a bit different to anything i've seen and wanted to know if anyone can see any issues with it.

What I'm doing is...

1. I have a httpmodule that does a server.transfer(); to a blank html page on the first request of a user visit.
2. On this blank html page is some javascript that detects the viewport
   width/height and touch capability. The js then saves this info to a
   client cookie and then redirects (via window.location) to the
   originally requested page.
3. When the httpmodule gets hit again, it reads the viewport
   and touch screen details from the client cookie.  If touch is
   available or the viewport width is less than say 480px then the
   httpmodule will redirect (via Response.Redirect()) to the mobile
   version of the website.

Is there any stumbling block I will likely encounter by doing this?

I should note that the tablet version of the site is the same as the mobile, which is why I want to redirect to this version if touch is available.

Comment: can you share your site to see it live ? The quick issues here for me is, what if not cookie and/or no javascript available. And maybe some screen flickering at that. And of course what if the viewport report false informations, or not at all.

Comment: im not too concerned if there are no cookies or javascript available as there are already fall backs for that. the flickering could be an issue though i guess

Comment: I think there's enough in `Aristos` and `jim68000` answers for you to think about a different approach. I personally don't like the idea redirecting **all** clients to a blank test page - this test can be done on the requested page and *only* redirect *if* necessary.

Comment: @MakkyNZ I think that you can do the same with out the server.transfer, just make this test ones just before the body of your page. So by default you show the normal page, and if you see a mobile page you redirect him via javascript on the mobile pages and its stay there, before the rest of the body load.

Comment: ideally i dont want to send the contents of the normal page to the client when they aren't gonna use it.  I'm using server.transfer so that the URL wont change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
any issues with it
```

1. Is not SEO friendly for sure.
2. Its not working if the user did not have javascript enable
3. Its have flickering if the cookie is not saved, or is disabled.
4. With the server transfer if you make any post, and any of the cookie or javascript fail, then the will also lose the post data.

Its nice idea general, but I think that you also need to check this thinks before the first server transfer. With your method you can avoid to keep an updated database with all the browser info's, I think that sounds good, but its need to be tested if its work smoothly in real world, and also make some more tests before the first server-trasnfer .

Answer (score 2):

Two issues I can see: latency and touch event availability.

Round trip times are enormously extended over mobile networks: you're looking at about 500ms over 3G for an empty page request. Therefore request - redirect - redirect is about a second of extra latency before the user sees anything. I don't think you'll see flicker - as some commenters suggest - you'll just see nothing for a second, which doesn't seem like a positive experience.

Regarding touch: not all mobile devices are touch based and some that are (Windows Mobile 7) don't have the ontouch* events. You'll need to track these separately.

Viewports are slippery things too: if you aren't forcing the viewport width though a meta tag you'll find a large number of your target devices are missed by a viewport test because they'll claim to be 1024px.

As the touch-enabled devices (iOS, Android etc) all support CSS media queries wouldn't this be a better way to go?

It might be worth taking a look at the RESS (REsponsive design with Server Side components) approach championed by people like Luke Wroblewski: http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1392

Comment: i considered the whole non-touch thing for windows and had the fallback of checking the width as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what the benefit of css media queries will be since it's server side that needs to know if the user is mobile.  the mobile site is a completely different site

Comment: Yeah, they can all be worked around but the problem[1] is that the more exceptions you build in the closer you get to just maintaining a database of devices keyed on user-agent. There's no easy answer: it's a tradeoff between how important mobile access is to your product and how much time you have to support them.

CSS: You could always drop a pixel with the results of the media-query in it to notify the server of the type of device? 
 
` `
[1] Only a problem if you subscribe to the 'user-agents are evil' PoV. I worked for a telco and that's how we did it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Media Queries which is CSS based and should sort website accordingly.
You can detect screen size on the fly and change css accordingly.

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: I'm not sure what the benefit of css media queries will be since it's server side that needs to know if the user is mobile in my case.  the mobile site is a completely different site

Comment: oops sorry, i thought you needed it for client side.